# monitoring data read/write speed to storage unit in linux

Tags: monitoring, file-transfer

Running rhel 7.7 on a server having a dell powervault storage unit.

I wish to test the read/write speed from my head node to the `/data` mount point which is NFS over infiniband.  I want to to observe read/write speeds to this *high speed storage unit*, and I have created one 50GB tar file I'd like to move back and forth.  How can I see what speed that happens at?

Comment: Suggest `bonnie++`. Either a Red Hat package (if there is one) or through a web search or https://sourceforge.net/projects/bonnie/

Answer (score 1):

`bonnie++` is an interesting program.  It was nice because it is available on EPEL and can easily be installed via `yum install bonnie++`

Because I am impatient I did not get far with it and I found the following to be more useful to satisfy my needs right now.  This was from the bonnie++ website https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/599-benchmark-disk-io-with-dd-and-bonnie

```
time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=[PATH] bs=[BLOCK_SIZE]k count=[LOOPS] && sync"
```

I have not really run this `dd` using `time` to ground, but for anyone interested in doing this that linux disk caching can be a *problem* such that for reads it is recommended to create one disk file with size greater than RAM, then create a different one to purge any remnants of the first one being in RAM that would skew results, then do a read of the first file.  I suspect a `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` would also be useful here to get good read/write results.